# How to make a FAQ dialog or pop up screen in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a dialog /pop up in jQuery Mobile. I am able to make it, but I have few issues when My content is more it should cover all 90% width, but it is covering 50% width.

Secondly why is there no formatting in Question and answer string(it should be left align mean Question and answer come together with break line) but in my case they are not coming together.

How to make **str** left align so that it is readable and how to take 90% width?

http://jsfiddle.net/5anNC/3/

```
function infoAlert(text) {
    var popupDialogId = 'popupDialog';
    $('<div class="aa" data-role="popup" id="' + popupDialogId + '" data-confirmed="no" data-transition="pop" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:500px;"> \
                        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">\
                            <h1>Info</h1>\
                        </div>\
                        <div role="main" class="ui-content">\
                            <h3 class="ui-title">' + text + '</h3>\
                            <a href="#" class="common-button ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b optionConfirm" data-rel="back">OK</a>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>')
        .appendTo($.mobile.pageContainer);
    var popupDialogObj = $('#' + popupDialogId);
    popupDialogObj.trigger('create');
    popupDialogObj.popup();
    popupDialogObj.popup('open');
    popupDialogObj.find(".optionConfirm").first().on('click', function () {

        $(popupDialogObj).remove();
        return false;
       // popupDialogObj.attr('data-confirmed', 'yes');
    });
}
```

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5anNC/4/ ?

Comment: @ezanker thanks I looking for same ..can we add "ok" and "cancel" button on top ..Thanks

Comment: Yes, the same way you added the OK button at the bottom. Just put the markup in the correct place.

Comment: thanks please post your answer i will make..But I one problem http://jsfiddle.net/5anNC/5/

Comment: In this fiddle when you scroll contend my "ok" button also scroll .can we scroll only Question and answer string (other word str or below version).can we add button below the version text(version 2.1.1).ok button, info header ,version text is fixed .only scroll Question and anwser string

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5anNC/6/